# Preventing multiprocessing "runaway bugs"

Tags: python, windows, linux, multiprocessing, process

The OS will not like it if you use multiprocessing and accidentally end up [creating processes without limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697640/multiprocessing-bomb).

Is there any simple solution that prevents this from happening (say, by limiting total number of processes, either in Python or in the OS)?

I use Windows, and it behaves really badly (requires hard reboot) when I make a mistake like that. So I'd love it if there's some code that I can wrap around / add to my application and prevent this from happening.

Comment: If this is a windows question- why is it tagged Linux?

Comment: Because ideally I want a solution for Linux and a solution for Windows! Sorry I wasn't clear about it... Obviously a 50% solution is still better than nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is create a short 'trip-wire' type module and import it as well as multiprocessing.  The trip-wire module will raise an exception if it detects a multiprocessing infinite loop.

Mine looks like this:

```
#mp_guard.py
"""tracks invocation by creating an environment variable; if that
variable exists when next called a loop is in progress"""

import os

class Brick(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        Exception.__init__(self, "Your machine just narrowly avoided becoming"
                                 " a brick!")

if 'MP_GUARD' in os.environ:
    raise Brick

os.environ['MP_GUARD'] = 'active'
```

And in the main .py file:

```
import mp_guard
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can use the [setrlimit(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall (with `RLIMIT_NPROC`) to limit the number of processes (e.g. to avoid [fork bombs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)). This syscall is interfaced thru the bash [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) (or zsh `limit`) builtin. Python has some [binding](http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html) to this syscall.

<sup>I have no idea if something similar exist under Windows.</sup>

Comment: As far as I can tell, nothing exists for Windows... sucks for them :-(

Comment: If so, it sucks indeed. Even when Windows goes into shutdown mode, it seems unable to stop the proliferation of processes. You'd think it would be easy for Win 7 to block any new user-created processes when it's trying to shut down...

Comment: Linux doesn't suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can create "a job", I'm not an expert in python, so I dont't know if theres is any binding for creating windows jobs. The Windows API function is *CreateJobObject*. A job object is (to some extent) equivalent of Unix "process group". You can apply certain limitations both on the job object as a whole and to each process separately (e.g. max processes in job). You could create a job object, assign number of processes limit to it and then assign your own process to the job object. What you may be looking for is *CreateJobObject*, *SetInformationJobObject* + **JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION** + **JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_ACTIVE_PROCESS**. Again: this is Windows API, I'm not sure if you have any 'bindings' to python related to these functions.