# Windows multiprocessing

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

As I have discovered windows is a bit of a pig when it comes to multiprocessing and I have a questions about it.

The pydoc states you should [protect the entry point of a windows application when using multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).

Does this mean only the code which creates the new process?

For example

### Script 1

```
import multiprocessing

def somemethod():
    while True:
        print 'do stuff'

# this will need protecting
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=somemethod).start()

# this wont
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=somemethod).start()
```

In this script you need to wrap this in if **main** because the line in spawning the process.
**But what about if you had?**

### Script 2

**file1.py**

```
import file2
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Aclass().start()
```

**file2.py**

```
import multiprocessing
ITEM = 0
def method1():
    print 'method1'

method1()

class Aclass(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Aclass'
        super(Aclass, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        print 'stuff'
```

**What would need to be protected in this instance?**
**What would happen if there was a if __main__ in File 2, would the code inside of this get executed if a process was being created?**

*NOTE: I know the code will not compile. It's just an example.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compulsory usage of if \_\_name\_\_=="\_\_main\_\_" in windows while using multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360686/compulsory-usage-of-if-name-main-in-windows-while-using-multiprocessi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The pydoc states you should protect the entry point of a windows application when using multiprocessing.

My interpretation differs: the documentations states

> the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process).

So importing your module (`import mymodule`) should not create new processes. That is, you can avoid starting processes by protecting your process-creating code with an

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
```

because the code in the ... will only run when your program is run as main program, that is, when you do

```
python mymodule.py
```

or when you run it as an executable, but not when you `import` the file.

So, to answer your question about the `file2`: no, you do not need protection because no process is started during the `import file2`.

Also, if you put an `if __name__ == '__main__'` in `file2.py`, it would not run because `file2` is imported, not executed as main program.

**edit:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697640/multiprocessing-bomb) is an example of what can happen when you do not protect your process-creating code: it might just loop and create a ton of processes.