# Pyspark multiprocessing using pool.map()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark, python-multiprocessing

I am calling `full_item()` for each element of a list `size_DF` and passing some parameters to the function.

```
map(lambda x : object.full_item(sc, Database, len(x), end_date),size_DF)
```

map function is working but it is taking more time as list contains more elements.

I tried the multiprocessing but getting the error as below:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool()

pool.map(lambda x : object.full_item(sc, Database, len(x), end_date),size_DF)
```

> cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute
>   lookup **builtin**.function failed

Please help and let me know how can i proceed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compulsory usage of if \_\_name\_\_=="\_\_main\_\_" in windows while using multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360686/compulsory-usage-of-if-name-main-in-windows-while-using-multiprocessi)

Comment: all multiprocessing stuff have to be inside the `if __name__=='__main__':` block

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, yes it's true for windows machines, but it's not the issue here. The issue is that multiprocessing module cannot serialize one of OP objects.

Comment: I have put all the stuff inside if __name__=='__main__': block but still getting the same issue.