# Multiprocessor Numerical Adder

Tags: python, windows, python-multiprocessing, python-3.7

So I am currently involved in a university project looking at thousands of samples of genetic data for cancer patients, might program was going to take too long to run so I used multiprocessing, it worked fine on an apple mac my friend borrowed me,but the moment I transferred it over to a university windows system it has failed and im unsure why the program doesn't work anymore.

I decided to strip my code as simply as possible to see the error,my program itself without the multiprocessing element to speed up the number of samples works fine. I believe the problem revolves around the code below. Instead of placing my very long program ive switched out it for a simple addition, and it still does not work, uses a very high cpu and I cannot see where I am going wrong. Kind Regards.

Expected result is instant 5,15,25,35 instantaneously, I have windows 10 on my computer Im currently using.

---

```
 import multiprocessing
 from multiprocessing import Pool
 import collections
 value=collections.namedtuple('value',['vectx','vecty'])
 Values=(value(vectx=0,vecty=5),value(vectx=5,vecty=10),value(vectx=10,vecty=15),value(vectx=15,vecty=20))
 print(1)
 def Alter(x):
   vectx=x.vectx
   vecty=x.vecty
   Z=(vectx+vecty)
   return(Z)
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     with Pool(2) as p:
          result=p.map(Alter, Values)
 print(2)
 new=[]
 for i in result:
     new.append(i)
 print(new)
```

Comment: I've attempted to put your code in your question but I may not have gotten all the indentation correct. Please take a look and fix if needed.

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: `if name == 'main':` should be `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: I have updated the code ,please can I have feedback.

Comment: Your indentation is not correct - starting at `if __name__ == '__main__':` - please fix.

Comment: I have resolved the small discrepancy , now please can I be provided a useful link to allow me to progress .

Comment: I would also recommend taking a look at numpy. You can handle large matrices easily, and even if you use multithreading and multiprocessing, it will still speed things up because your batches will be larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why exactly but this part

```
 print(2)
 new=[]
 for i in result:
     new.append(i)
 print(new)
```

needs to be *in* the suite of the if statement. Similar to the example in [the documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(2) as p:
        result=p.map(Alter, Values)
    print(2)
    new=[]
    for i in result:
        new.append(i)
    print(new)
```

---

I suspect that - [`Compulsory usage of if __name__==“__main__” in windows while using multiprocessing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360686/compulsory-usage-of-if-name-main-in-windows-while-using-multiprocessi) - may be relevant.

If you run your **original** code from a command shell (like PowerShell or command prompt) with `python -m mymodulename` you will see all the *stuff* that is going on - Tracebacks from multiple spawned processes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance, such a small tweak but with massive implication for if my program works, thank you.

Comment: Hi again, okay so my program works independently, and the code tweak ive made allows multiprocessing to occur, why isn't the program working, it works on the mac but doesn't work on the windows. Should I post my entire program.

Comment: That sounds like a different question. You'll need to include enough cose for people to easily reproduce the problem. - [mcve]. - `why isn't the program working, it works on the mac but doesn't work on the windows.` - you will need to be clear what you mean by this. The example code in this question with the indentation changes does work, it produces the expected result.