# How can I run processes in Python?

Tags: python

I searched some examples in the official python page, others pages and also books, but processes doesn't work. In this example I only print a message that is passed as a parameter to each function. I don't know why, but processes don't work in Windows because I tried in 3 different computers(2 with Windows and other with Linux) and a web page to program with Python and process don't work in Windows

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

def worker(msg):
    
    for i in range(0, 10):
        
        print(msg, end='', flush=True) # <----- print msg

print('Starting')

t2 = Process(target=worker, args=('A',))
t3 = Process(target=worker, args=('B',))
t4 = Process(target=worker, args=('C',))

t2.start() # <---------------------------
t3.start() # <----- they don't work -----
t4.start() # <---------------------------

t2.join()
t3.join()
t4.join()

print('Done')
```

This is printed as output:

> Starting
>
> Done

Comment: Your edited example works for me - I get this output: https://i.imgur.com/jt0vDtJ.png

Comment: Did you forget the: `if __name__ == '__main__':` thing?

Comment: I tried this example in windows in 2 computers and a web page with python, I don't know why, but proccesses don't work in windows.

Comment: It works for me with Pycharm under Windows, but with the “if name main” thing.

Comment: Thank you guys, It is due to "if __name__ == '__main__'", but why I have to do it of this way?

Comment: Maybe [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20360812/13354437) could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to you guys I could solve this.

The error was due to that I didn't use `if __name__ == "__main__":`, but other error is that I used eclipse with pydev, I don't know why, but I can't do it with eclipse and pydev (I think is limited) until I tried it in sublime text 3 and pycharm.

Answer (score 2):

You're not waiting for the child processes to stop; once the parent program ends, they're killed.

Add

```
t2.join()
t3.join()
t4.join()
```

after your `print('Done')` to give them a chance to do their thing.

Also, `args` must be a tuple of arguments, not a single string.

Comment: I usually add: `print('Done')` to the very end of my scripts to show that it ended when I wanted it to end. Do you think the OP wanted this as well?

Comment: If I use "join()" and I remove "sleep()" It still doesn't work.

Comment: @quamrana Perhaps it was "done starting"? :)