# Different behavior of a Python script in VSCode on Windows 10 vs. Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, linux, windows, idioms

I'm using Version: 1.73.1 of VSCode with Python 3.10. This script:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo(i):
  print(i)

for i in range(12):
  Process(target=foo, args=(i,)).start()
```

runs fine inside VSCode on Ubuntu 22.04.1, but fails on Windows 10 with this error message:

```
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...
```

Indeed, adding the "proper idiom" makes it run correctly. Why this difference between the two OSes?

Comment: Which python version are you running on which OS?

Comment: @tink Sorry for the omission. Python 3.10 on both OSes. Specifically, 3.10.6 on Ubuntu and 3.10.8 on Windows.

Comment: Please edit that into your question ;) ... ta.

Comment: @tink I did before I answered your comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360686/compulsory-usage-of-if-name-main-in-windows-while-using-multiprocessi and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222534/python-multiprocessing-on-windows-if-name-main

Comment: What's the name of your python script ?

Comment: @Philippe `so-4.py`

Comment: This article seems to explain well : https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/differences-between-multiprocessing-windows-and-linux/#:~:text=On%20Linux%2C%20when%20you%20start,starts%20and%20the%20code%20reruns.