# Code wont excuted by order in __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, program-entry-point

Im trying some multiprocessing as the example code below, it should print message from `01,02,03,hello world,04,05`, but it went `01,02,01,05,03,hello world,04,05` instead, why `02` back to `01` then jump to `05`, back to `03`, why am i missing here, how to let it run by order, Thank you!

```
from multiprocessing import *

# large data/complex use multiprocessing , else use odinary function
q = Queue() # comm between parent n child proces
    

def f1(x,q):
    print('03')
    x = x + " world"
    q.put(x)


def main_f():
    print('01')
    mp = Process(target=f1,args=("hello",q,))

    if __name__ == '__main__': # only happen once, else ex 4 process to 16 to 64 endless
        print('02')

        mp.start()
        print(q.get())
        mp.join()

        print('04')

main_f()
print('05')
```

I expect the message print from `01,02,03,hello world,04,05`

Comment: Show us exactly how you run this code.

Comment: The order of output is not guaranteed in concurrent execution like multiprocessing. It can change with every run. If you want the output to be in a specific order, you can use a queue to pass messages between processes and ensure that the processes execute in a specific order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compulsory usage of if \_\_name\_\_=="\_\_main\_\_" in windows while using multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360686/compulsory-usage-of-if-name-main-in-windows-while-using-multiprocessi)

Comment: @AhmedAEK not excatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When you do multiprocessing under a platform that uses the *spawn* method to create new processes, then any code at global scope that is not within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block will first be executed by the child process in order to initialize its storage prior to invoking the worker function `f1`.**

In your posted code, when the child process is created it will therefore execute the following statements in order:

1. `from multiprocessing import *`
2. `q = Queue()` # create global queue
3. `def f1(x, q):` # create function definition
4. `def main_f():` # create function definition
5. `main_f()` # call main_f
6. `print('05')`

In reality the only statement that needs to be executed by the child process before the worker method `f1` is invoked is statement #3 above, which defines the worker function for the child process.

Statement 1 imports a package not used by your child process. Doing this does not prevent the program from running correctly but Python is spending time performing animport that is not used.

Statement #2 needlessly creates a new queue instance in the child process distinct from the one created in the main process. It would be disastrous if your child process used this since it would be putting elements on a different queue than the one the main process is getting from. Fortunately, function `f1` is not referencing and using the queue that is passed as an argument.

Statement #4 defines a function not used by the child process. It doesn't prevent the program from running but is wasteful.

Statement #5 invokes `main_f`. **This is where your troubles begins.** All the code within `main_f` that is not within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block will get executed immediately before your worker function is invoked. This is what is causing an extra '01' to be printed.

Statement #6 likewise is what is causing an extra '05' to be printed.

At the minimum to get your program working correctly, your code should therefore be:

```py
from multiprocessing import *

def f1(x,q):
    print('03')
    x = x + " world"
    q.put(x)


def main_f():
    # large data/complex use multiprocessing, else use ordinary function
    q = Queue() # comm between parent n child process

    print('01')
    mp = Process(target=f1,args=("hello",q,))

    print('02')

    mp.start()
    print(q.get())
    mp.join()

    print('04')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_f()
```

If we want to eliminate all possible inefficiencies, i.e. prevent unnecessary statements from being executed when the child process is initialized, then:

```py
def f1(x,q):
    print('03')
    x = x + " world"
    q.put(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import *

    def main_f():
        # large data/complex use multiprocessing, else use ordinary function
        q = Queue() # comm between parent n child process

        print('01')
        mp = Process(target=f1,args=("hello",q,))

        print('02')

        mp.start()
        print(q.get())
        mp.join()

        print('04')

    main_f()
```