# Unexpected error in Python code with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I get a error when I run this code.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count
import time


def counter(num):
    count = 0
    while count < num:
        count += 1


def main():

   print("cpu count:", cpu_count())

    a = Process(target=counter, args=(500000000,))
    b = Process(target=counter, args=(500000000,))

    a.start()
    b.start()

   print("processing...")

    a.join()
    b.join()

    print("Done!")
    print("finished in:", time.perf_counter(), "seconds")


main()
```

I was expecting Python to print up to 1000000000 but it just gives me a unexpected error. I am not sure what if **name** == "**main**": does so I have not used it.

Comment: "I am not sure what `if __name__ == "__main__":` does so I have not used it." Removing that would be the first problem :) See also [Compulsory usage of `if __name__=="__main__"` in windows while using multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20360686/11082165) and linked questions.

Comment: removing what??

Comment: _but it just gives me a unexpected error_ Are we supposed to guess what the error is?

Comment: @SkrugNuggsta the `if __name__ == "__main__": ` guard.

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...
        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood how time.perf_counter() works

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you must write:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

On non-Linux machines, Python starts new processes but having them re-read the main file.  In your original code, each time a new process is started, it starts up another ten processes.

You need to make sure that `main()` is only executed once.

Comment: _"On non-Linux machines, Python starts new processes"_ fun fact, that fact this this _isn't_ the default on unix systems is [now considered a mistake](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84559). Current sites are on making `spawn` the default start method on unix systems as well in Python 3.14.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure a duration you need to note both start and end times then subtract one from the other.

Something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import perf_counter

def counter(num):
    for _ in range(num):
        ...
    return num

N = 500000000
NPROCS = 2

def main():
    start = perf_counter()

    with Pool() as pool:
        for ar in [pool.apply_async(counter, (N,)) for _ in range(NPROCS)]:
            print(ar.get())

    end = perf_counter()

    print(f'Duration {end-start:.2f}s')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
500000000
500000000
Duration 8.61s
```