# share const global varible in python mutiprocessing?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

Basically what I am trying to do is this:

```
def func1(a):
    return theBigStaticVar+a

a=[1,2,3...100]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool() 
theBigStaticVar=10
outputs = pool.map(func1, a) 

print(outputs)

pool.close()
```

which will give me an error `NameError: name 'theBigStaticVar' is not defined`

`theBigStaticVar`  represents a huge chunk of data (about 20MB in my real case), and will only be viewed but not modified in func1. So I assume it can be shared among different processes, without worrying about locking or sync. How can I send this data into func1 efficiently?

The only way I can think about is

```
def func1(pair):
    return pair[0]+pair[1]

theBigStaticVar=10
pairs=[[1,theBigStaticVar],[2,theBigStaticVar ],[3,theBigStaticVar],...[100,theBigStaticVar]]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool() 
outputs = pool.map(func1, pairs) 

print(outputs)

pool.close()
```

But it seems that it will copy the `theBigStaticVar` for 100 times. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Separate processes mean you have your own memory space. That means you need to perform some kind of explicit communication across processes if you want anything to be bidirectionally shared (vs "copied from parent to child exactly once when the child is started", which in forking models you get for free). This is _the whole reason_ you get the performance enhancements of not having to deal with the Python GIL -- if access to shared objects had to be coordinated across your processes by locking, multiprocessing would have the same performance problems as multithreading in addition to its own.

Comment: (beyond that, multiprocessing often _isn't_ the right tool; I see a lot of people try to use it in circumstances where it makes their software's performance worse rather than better; would need to know more about your real use case to know if you had one of those, of course).

Comment: What exactly are you actually storing in your big static variable - is it an image?  A dict? What do your multiple processes do with it exactly? How long do they run for typically?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you are creating the variable after the `Pool()`. Besides, use `if __name__ == "__main__"` to call the method. You can see more information about the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360686/compulsory-usage-of-if-name-main-in-windows-while-using-multiprocessi).

See the code below working:

```
import multiprocessing

a=[1, 2, 3, 100]

def func1(x):
    return theBigStaticVar+x

theBigStaticVar=10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        print(p.map(func1, a))
```

Comment: I see. Your method works, but it seems to be even slower than my native try.

i notice if we do

``theBigStaticVar=10
print("hello")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        print(p.map(func1, a))``
, then the hello will be printed many times. Does it mean that the code there was executed for multiple times? because my `theBigStaticVar` is not gain from void; getting this data also cost several second a time.

Answer (score 1):

multiprocessing.Pool allows you to specify an initialiser function whereby you can conveniently place your big chunk of data into global space.

Here's an example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def ipp(v):
    global theBigDataVar
    theBigDataVar = v

def process(n):
    return theBigDataVar + n

def main():
    theBigDataVar = 10
    with Pool(initializer=ipp, initargs=(theBigDataVar,)) as pool:
        print(pool.map(process, range(1, 10)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: How is this any different, please, from putting `theBigDataVar = 10` left-aligned on the line after `from multiprocessing import Pool` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell In this particular case it's no different but I offer this as a generic solution. It comes into its own when dealing with objects that cannot be pickled. Even if the "shared" object can be pickled, this technique is of benefit if the object is large - i.e., the pickling overhead is removed

Comment: Cool - thanks for taking the time to answer.