# Joblib Parallel + Cython hanging forever

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cython, joblib

I have a very weird problem while creating a Python extension with Cython that uses `joblib.Parallel`.

The following code works as expected:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from math import sqrt

print(Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(sqrt)(x) for x in range(4)))
```

The following code hangs forever:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def mult(x):
    return x*3

print(Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(mult)(x) for x in range(4)))
```

I have no clues why. I use the following `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("file.pyx")
)
```

I create the extension with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` and I import it as `import file`.

Thank you!

Comment: If it's multithreading (rather than multiprocessing), then Cython doesn't release the GIL by default so it will hang forever. This is usually the cause of cases like this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't joblib.Parallel multiprocessing?

Comment: A quick look suggests that joblib.Parallel can pick a number of backends, and I'm not sure what it defaults to.

Answer (score 2):

After some time I finally found the solution:
there is a deadlock while pickling the program status to send it to different CPUs.
I am not totally sure of the cause, but inspecting the source code, it looked as if new threads are generated to pickle the objects and these threads are the ones to cause the deadlock.

Once the processes are generated they run normally: manually creating the processes through the library `multiprocessing` fixes the problem.

Alternatively, you can use `multiprocessing.Pool` manually specifying the `start_method`:

```
from multiprocessing import get_context()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with get_context("spawn").Pool() as pool:
        ...
```

You can freely choose `spawn` or `forkserver` as `start_method`.

Visit [this page](https://codewithoutrules.com/2018/09/04/python-multiprocessing/) if you want more information.