# Ubuntu, cx_Freeze and multiprocessing.Manager() conflict in case "spawn" type processes

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, multiprocessing, cx-freeze

#### Env:

Ubuntu - 18.04
Python - 3.6.6
cx_Freeze - 6.1

#### Code:

Simple **main_script.py** file (example in repository - https://github.com/Yuriy-Leonov/cython_multiprocessing_issue )

```
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("step-1")
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")
    print("step-2")
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    print("step-3")
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    print("step-4")
    s_dict = manager.dict()
    print("finish")
```

And **setup.py** (for cx_Freeze):

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("main_script.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Example",
    options={
        "build_exe": {
            "replace_paths": [("*", "")]
        },
    },
    executables=executables
)
```

#### Issue:

After building executable file via command `python setup.py build` I ran it and console log contained following:

```
step-1
step-2
step-3
step-1
step-2
step-3
step-1
step-2
step-3
...
```

And infinite processes are spawned.
I understand that `multiprocessing.Manager()` should spawn "server" process. But can't get clue of current behaviorand and how to force it to create "shared dict"

#### Important:

`multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")` can't be changed and required due to main program behavior.

#### Question:

How to achive of creating `manager.dict()` in current configuration?

#### PS:

There is no issue if run with regular `python <filename>`(obvious)

Comment: If it's a pure python script and compiling it with cython generates different runtime behavior than if you're running under a regular a python interpreter then I think it's by definition a bug in cython.

Comment: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3262 seems relevant

Comment: I have tried to improve my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47360452/5769463. Because it applies to any frozen python script and not only Cython - it shows what is going wrong, references bug-entry which is not yet resolved  and also proposes a do-it-yourself solution, which can at least serve as a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand what `set_start_method("spawn")` does.

It does not make sense to run your script as a pre-compiled executable and expect `set_start_method("spawn")` to just work, because `"spawn"` here means "start my child processes by reinvoking the interpreter", but the "interpreter" is your pre-compiled program!

When you run your program, you get a fork bomb because the multiprocessing module tries to spawn the following processes:

```sh
$ ./main_script --multiprocessing-fork tracker_fd=6 pipe_handle=8
$ ./main_script -S -E -c 'from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker import main;main(5)'
```

That's not going to work with your pre-compiled program. You will need to explicitly `exec` into the python interpreter or handle these cases if you want `set_start_method("spawn")` to work.

Comment: well, actually for Windows this code works well even with "pre-compiled".