# Python 3.7.7 Subinterpreter fails at multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cython, cpython

Assume the following python-program from the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) (The Process class):

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Running this code against my **3.7.7** interpreter on my **Windows** machine works, as expected, without any problems. However, running the same code against a [Subinterpreter](https://lwn.net/Articles/820424/) created in `C++` fails with the following error (no Exception actually, the following error just gets printed to the console):

> unrecognised option '-c'

I assume that the reason for this error is to be found in [spawn.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py) (within the multiprocessing module, line 89):

```
...
return [_python_exe] + opts + ['-c', prog, '--multiprocessing-fork']
...
```

I could create my new process via [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). This works, but the spawned process should be a child-process, not a completely independent process.

My question:

Why does this error occur? Is there any way to spawn a child process within a Subinterpreter via `multiprocessing.Process`?

Thank you!

**UPDATE 1**

[As suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47325297/compiling-executable-with-dask-or-joblib-multiprocessing-with-cython-results-in/47360452#47360452), adding `freeze_support` fixes the error, but a new one occurs:

> unrecognised option '--multiprocessing-fork'

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47360452/5769463

Comment: @ead Thanks, didn't see that one. I updated my question.

Comment: The issue is probably in main of your c++ program, but we don’t see it.

Comment: @ead Sorry but Im a C++ noob. Iam using `pybind` to run my Python-File via `eval_file`. Is this enough information? Sorry I can't share any code as it is a safety critical application..